# CSS width: Use min-content above a certain width

Tags: javascript, css

Update: Added an additional image and added red arrows to more clearly point to my issue.

I'm trying to style a tooltip with text properly. the issue I have, is I used a max-width value to force the text to wrap beyond a certain width.

Then I found out about min-content, but it shrinks to the largest word in the text. So for long bits of text, this creates a long vertical tooltip.

Is there a way to combine both approaches, and use min-content only beyond a certain minimal width, while allowing very short texts to also display right?

Here are the 3 examples:

The first, with a `max-width: 120px`, as you can see there is unnecessary space on each side of the text, compared to the smaller one (which is correct).

[image]
[image]

Using `width: min-content`, everything shrinks to the largest word, making it hard to read.

[image]

A final example using `width: min-content`, with text short enough I wouldn't want it to wrap

[image]

Comment: padding:0; - try it

Comment: Why are you hung up on using min-content? It's not even fully supported. What's wrong with just giving it a fixed-width of like 200px?

Comment: @StefanBob The first example is that quick and easy solution. It works, small tooltips don't wrap until they have to because they are extending beyond max-width.

My problem is with the extra space that it leaves in the tooltip on either side, because the text is centered, and the width is maxed to 120px.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: inline-block, min-width, max-width, padding` and you will get what you are looking for.

```css
.tooltip {
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <span>Little tooltip</span>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span>Very long tooltip but not that long as expected, looks cool.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is what I had in my first example, and what I was trying to avoid. The longer tooltip has extra space on the sides compared to your small tooltip, because the width is forced to 150px.